# Writing form details to a text file in Windows Phone

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7

I am creating a Windows Phone App using VB.NET and what I want to do is have the user fill out a form within the app, and then when they press a send button I need to app to write these details to a text file, so I can then attach this to an email.

However the problem is I have no idea how to successfully write these details to a text file, I was wondering if anybody had an example of how it is done or just some advice that may help me to find what path I need to take in order to resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: use `StringBuilder` to get information from form then write the output string to `text file` using `File stream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to send an email on Windows Phone is via the `EmailComposeTask` API.

Sample VB.NET code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1):

```
Dim emailComposeTask as EmailComposeTask= new EmailComposeTask()

emailComposeTask.Subject = "message subject"
emailComposeTask.Body = "message body"
emailComposeTask.To = "recipient@example.com"
emailComposeTask.Cc = "cc@example.com"
emailComposeTask.Bcc = "bcc@example.com"

emailComposeTask.Show()
```

The downside of this API is that it doesn't allow attaching files.

So if you have the requirement to send the email with an attachment, you'll have to rely on an external service.

Here is the code for creating a text file in a `MemoryStream`:

```
Dim memoryStrm As New MemoryStream() 
Dim writer As New StreamWriter(memoryStrm)
writer.WriteLine("Line 1")
writer.WriteLine("Line 2")
```

You could send this file to a web service that will in turn send the email.